# How do I automate builds using App Center?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, continuous-integration, appcenter

I am using App Center as CI for my application. I have to configure all the branches manually against which I need to build.

**What I Want**

If somebody creates a feature branch from develop/master and pushes the code, then App Center should start running automatically like CircleCI build etc.

Is this not possible in App Center?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. You need to use [app center fastlane plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/fastlane-plugin-appcenter). You need to use `appcenter_upload` function. SSH has nothing to do with the whole process.

In your `FastFile` you need to configure a lane in following manner:

```yaml
  desc 'Deploy a new version to the AppCenter'
  lane :upload_to_appcenter do |options|
    config = fetch_configuration(for_release_type: options[:release_type], for_project_dir: ENV['PROJECT_DIR'])

    gradle(
      task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'Release',
      properties: {
        "AppCenterEnvironment" => options[:release_type],
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV['KEYSTORE'],
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV['KEYSTORE_PASSWORD'],
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV['KEYALIAS'],
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => ENV['KEYALIAS_PASSWORD'],
        "VersionPatchNumber" => config['app_version_patch_number']
      })

    perform_backup

    appcenter_upload(
      app_name: config['appcenter_name'],
      file: lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH],
      destinations: '*',
      release_notes: default_changelog,
      notify_testers: true,
      mapping: 'app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt'
    )
  end
```

In your CI pipeline yaml you'll have to have something line this:

```yaml
 - script: bundle exec fastlane upload_to_appcenter
    displayName: Upload to AppCenter
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')
    env:
      APPCENTER_TOKEN: $(APPCENTER_API_TOKEN)
      APPCENTER_OWNER_NAME: $(APPCENTER_OWNER)
      RSYNC_PASSWORD: $(RSYNC_PASSWORD)
```

This will push version for every change of the head of `development`.

Please look at the repo guide how you can provide `ENV` variable, also look at your CI how you can pass params from the yaml to `FastLane`.

Comment: This is to publish your build to appcenter. I am using appcenter ci where I need to configure each branches where I need to run CI. My question Is there any way to automate this ?

Comment: Any way to trigger build pipelines automatically when you push code in app center ?